# Laravel: Too few arguments to function

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

In my Laravel app, I have answers which are related to questions. In my controller I have a function to retrieve the user's answers.

While running this function, I have an error saying

> 'too few arguments to function'.

The issue is with the `$userId`, but I don't know why. This argument is not 'accepted' in my with 'method'.

Please help me out here.

```
public function get_user_answers($phaseId, $stepId, $userId)
    {
        $questions = Question::where('step_id', $stepId)
        ->with(array('answers' => function($query, $userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', $userId);
        }))
        ->get();

        if($questions) {
            return response()->json([
                'questions' => $questions,
            ], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'No questions were found.',
            ], 404);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show model of question and answer.

Comment: btw, `$questions` will always be `true` it will never be `false` as it is a Collection (object) .... objects are always "truthy" `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a outer parameter in callback function. You can try by using use like-

```
        ->with(array('answers' => function($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', $userId);
        }))
```

So after this change, your code will look like,

```
public function get_user_answers($phaseId, $stepId, $userId)
    {
        $questions = Question::where('step_id', $stepId)
        ->with(array('answers' => function($query) use ($userId) {
            $query->where('user_id', $userId);
        }))
        ->get();

        if($questions) {
            return response()->json([
                'questions' => $questions,
            ], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'No questions were found.',
            ], 404);
        }
    }
```